# Ember Link-to highlighting and nested routes

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to diagnose a problem with my route structure, where if I click on the link-to helper directly, it correctly highlights the parent... but if I reload the page and Ember restores the nested route, I lose the highlight.

Here are my routes:

```
App.Router.map(function(){

 this.resource('client', { path: '/:client_id' }, function(){

    this.resource('dashboard');

    this.resource('commview', { path: 'commview' }, function(){
        this.route('filters', { path: '/:serializedData' });
    });

    this.resource('pathview');

 });

});
```

And here's an example of the link-to in the application template:
`{{#link-to 'commview' client.id}}<span class="icon">Communications View</span>{{/link-to}}`

`client.id` maps to `:client_id` as you'd expect.

Any ideas? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up restructuring how the "clients" are arranged so that I could remove the specific client.id in the link-to helper, and that seems to have fixed it.